# Replacing guard by switch or if-else

Tags: swift, flutter

Below code is part of using [platform-channels](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) in [Flutter](https://flutter.io/) that is calling a native iOS function (i.e. [swift](https://swift.org/) function

```
batteryChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
    [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
    guard call.method == "getBatteryLevel" else {
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        return
    }
    self!.receiveBatteryLevel(result: result)
})
```

I need to add another check of the `call.method`, something like below.

```
call.method == "getText" else {
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
        return
}
self!.getText(result: result)
```

I did no understand what is the `Void in` and `guard` are! I know nothing about swift, so how can I use `if-else` or `switch` to check the above 2 values of `call.method`?

Comment: If you *know nothing about swift* please read [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you are providing a call handler to the batteryChannel object. The `(call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void` bit provides the parameters and return value for the call handler.

The `[weak self]` part is a "capture list" that prevents the closure from strongly capturing self and creating a retain cycle. Inside the closure `self` may be nil, so you need to protect against that case. I added a guard statement to simply return if self is nil in that case.

#### (Using `self!` to force-unwrap is bad, and will crash if self is `nil`. Don't do that.)

I suggest rewriting your code as a switch statement:

```
batteryChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
    [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }  //Make sure self isn't nil

    switch call.method {
      case "getBatteryLevel": 
        strongSelf.receiveBatteryLevel(result: result)
      case "getText":
        strongSelf.getText(result: result)
      default:  //Code for case where you don't recognize the call method
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
    }
})
```

### EDIT:

A `guard` statement says "make sure the following expression is true, or exit if it's not":

```
guard <boolean> else { code that exits scope }
```

When you were checking for only one possible call method, using a `guard` statement was ok. Your code said 'if the call method isn't "getBatteryLevel", exit.' You COULD rewrite that to say 'if the call method isn't "getBatteryLevel" or "getText", exit', but it seems cleaner to use a switch statement instead. That way your code either has a case to handle the call method or it falls through to the default case, which triggers the `result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)` method call.

You should read the Apple iBook "The Swift Programming Language." There are a lot of concepts and syntax that you are dealing with that you don't yet understand, and it takes some study. The first half of the iBook is a tutorial on the language, and an easy read.

Comment: Thanks a lot fo the detailed explanations and guidelines, appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a switch like this:

```
switch call.method {
    case "getBatteryLevel":
        self!.receiveBatteryLevel(result: result)
    case "getText":
        self!.getText(result: result)
    default:
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
}
```

The `(call: FlutterMethodCall, result: FlutterResult) -> Void in` part is just saying what type of closure you are writing. In this case, a closure that accepts two parameters `call` and `result` and returns nothing (`Void`).

Comment: Thanks, It is correct I'm doing the same thing inside the else, but I don't need both functions to be executed together, I need each function to be executed only with it's relevant 'call.methid'

Comment: @HasanAYousef How's that any different? The logic you want here is basically "If `call.method` is not getBatteryLevel or it is not getText, give a NotImplementedResult, then return". Can you clarify what you mean by "each function to be executed only with it's relevant 'call.method"?

Comment: @HasanAYousef Ah I didn't see the `receiveBatteryLevel` and `getText` calls! Now I get what you mean. See the edit.

Comment: Great minds think alike. I suggested a Switch statement too. It seems a lot clearer, and is easier to maintain than multiple if statements.

Comment: Note that the OP's use of `[weak self]` and `self!.getText(result:)` is prone to crashing. That bears correcting, as in my answer.